# The + system/machine

Tags: articles, zero-article

From Wikipedia:
*The internal combustion engine is perhaps the most common example of a heat engine, in which...*

The internal combustion engine = all (general) internal combustion engines. Systems/machine take "the" when they are explained as a thing in general, not a particular example. Am I correct?

How about "iron ore", which is C/U, as a thing in general?
*Iron ore contains some substances.*
No article?

Comment: You are correct, but iron ore is a substance (an uncountable noun) rather than a thing.

Comment: Good to hear that. I see. Thank you Kate for your help always.